# How to use R to create baseball Splits from Game Logs

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to use R to recreate Baseball Splits as found on MLB.com.  The splits are created from Game Logs and provide different cuts of the data. For example, home games vs. away games, day games vs. night games, August vs. September and many more all in one convenient table.  I believe the ratios (AVG, OBP SLG) can all be added via mutate once the basic splits have been totaled.

**My Question** is, what's the best and most efficient way to create these splits and how should the data be shaped.  The game log obviously has additional (hidden) column(s) that contain the Split topics. The nature of the problem leads me to believe purrr might be a tool to employ but I can't quite wrap my mind around how to approach this one.

Here is how I believe the data should be shaped and a [link to a sample game log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MundyMSDS/GAMELOG/main/SAMPLE_GAME_LOG.csv). I would appreciate any thoughts, ideas or solutions to this problem.

[image]

Links and images of Game Logs and Splits for National outfielder Juan Soto are set forth below.

Game Logs: [Juan Soto Game Log](https://www.mlb.com/player/juan-soto-665742?stats=gamelogs-r-hitting-mlb&year=2020)

Splits: [Juan Soto Game Splits](https://www.mlb.com/player/juan-soto-665742?stats=splits-r-hitting-mlb&year=2020)

[image: Game Log Image:]

Splits
[image: Splits]

Answer (score 3):

I've gone through the dataset, although I'm not sure if the `sum` values match, and neither the averages relative to the images above.

You're right about mutating for creating the values you suggest.

However, hopefully my approach can help you get what you're after.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

game.splits <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MundyMSDS/GAMELOG/main/SAMPLE_GAME_LOG.csv"
game.splits <- fread(game.splits, fill = TRUE)

game.splits.pivot <- game.splits
game.splits.pivot$Var1 <- ifelse(game.splits.pivot$Var1 %in% "HOME", 1, 0)
game.splits.pivot$Var2 <- ifelse(game.splits.pivot$Var2 %in% "NIGHT", 3, 2)
game.splits.pivot$Var3 <- ifelse(game.splits.pivot$Var3 %in% "SEPTEMBER", 5, 4)

game.splits.pivot <- game.splits.pivot %>% pivot_longer(-c(1:16, 20))
colnames(game.splits.pivot)[19] <- "name_c"
game.splits.pivot <- game.splits.pivot[, -c(17, 18)]
game.splits.pivot <- game.splits.pivot %>% pivot_longer(-c(1:3, 17))

#test
game.splits.pivot_test <- game.splits.pivot[, -c(1, 2, 3)]
game.splits.pivot_test <- aggregate(value ~ name_c + name, game.splits.pivot_test, sum)
game.splits.pivot_test <- game.splits.pivot_test %>% pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

lc_name <- tibble(name_c = 0:5, split = c("HOME", "AWAY", "DAY", "NIGHT", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER"))

game.splits.pivot_test <- game.splits.pivot_test %>% 
  inner_join(lc_name, by = "name_c") %>% 
  arrange(name_c) %>% 
  select(-name_c)

game.splits.pivot_test <- game.splits.pivot_test[, c(14, 3, 9, 6, 1, 2, 7, 10, 4, 8, 12, 11, 5, 13)]
```

A look into the dataset:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 14
  split        AB     R     H  `2B`  `3B`    HR   RBI    BB   IBB    SO    SB    CS    TB
  <chr>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 HOME         88    24    32     5     0     9    23    15     5    12     1     2    64
2 AWAY         66    15    22     9     0     4    14    26     7    16     5     0    43
3 DAY          29    21    18     4     0     5    17    12     4     3     4     0    37
4 NIGHT       125    18    36    10     0     8    20    29     8    25     2     2    70
5 AUGUST       90    21    33     6     0    11    25    13     1    13     1     1    72
6 SEPTEMBER    64    18    21     8     0     2    12    28    11    15     5     1    35
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be more straight-forward than I had thought. The following solution relies upon pivot_longer to shape the data and summarise_if to tally the splits - no rbinds or purrr needed.

```
library(tidyverse)
        
        game.splits <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MundyMSDS/GAMELOG/main/SAMPLE_GAME_LOG.csv"
        game.splits <- read_csv(game.splits)
        
        
        game.splits %>% 
          pivot_longer(Var1:Var3, names_to = "split") %>% 
          group_by(split) %>% 
          arrange(split) %>% 
          select(split, value, everything()) %>% 
          ungroup() %>% 
          select(split, value, everything()) %>% 
          select(-Date, -OPP) %>% 
          mutate(value = str_c(split, "_", value)) %>% 
          group_by(value) %>% 
          summarise_if(is.numeric, sum) %>% 
          mutate(value= str_replace(value, "(Var\\d_)",""))
    
    
        #> # A tibble: 6 x 14
        #>   value     AB     R     H    TB  `2B`  `3B`    HR   RBI    BB   IBB    SO    SB
        #>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
        #> 1 AWAY      88    24    32    64     5     0     9    23    15     5    12     1
        #> 2 HOME      66    15    22    43     9     0     4    14    26     7    16     5
        #> 3 DAY       29    21    18    37     4     0     5    17    12     4     3     4
        #> 4 NIGHT    125    18    36    70    10     0     8    20    29     8    25     2
        #> 5 AUGUST    90    21    33    72     6     0    11    25    13     1    13     1
        #> 6 SEPTE~    64    18    21    35     8     0     2    12    28    11    15     5
    
    Created on 2021-03-03 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```